# WPF binding set before application starts does not notify?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

In theory this code should provide me with a 300x300 window with a blue background from having the window's content bound to an object of type AstRootViewModel, however this doesn't seem to be the case.  I'm wondering it this is happening because I don't call astApplication.Run() until after I set the mainWindow.ViewModel property.  Using snoop to check the binding I have a blank content binding and it's flagged as an error with no error information.

**If it is the case that property notification does not occurr until the application Run method is called, then what would be the best way to resolve this in an MVVM friendly way?**

I have the following Entry point to a WPF application:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        settingsSource = LoadSettingsFile(".\\applicationSettings.xml");

        astApplication = new Application();
        mainWindow = new AstWindowView();

        mainWindowModel = new AstRootViewModel();
        dataModel = new AstDataModel(settingsSource);

        mainWindow.ViewModel = mainWindowModel;
        astApplication.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        astApplication.Run();
    }
```

The AstWindowView class implements the following significant code behind:

```
public partial class AstWindowView : Window
{
    public AstRootViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (AstRootViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ViewModel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(AstRootViewModel), typeof(Window), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public AstWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and the following significant XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AstViewResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Content>
    <Binding Path="ViewModel" Mode="Default" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</Window.Content>
```

The AstViewResources.xaml file defines the following DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AstRootViewModel}">
    <vw:AstRootView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And lastly, the AstRootView XAML contains the following significant XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SEL.MfgTestDev.AutomatedSettingsTransfer.View.AstRootView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="#FF000CFF"/>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting the DataContext for AstWindowView anywhere and your Binding has no explicit Source set. Are you seeing a binding error saying something to that effect in your debug output? Try adding after the InitializeComponent call in AstWindowView ctor (could also do it by changing the Binding in XAML):

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: @commits newbiemistakesuicide

Comment: better solution:

DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"